# Python assigning wrong dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

In my code:

```
line_x = 10
c = 'A'
d = 'B'
a = {}
a['one']='|   |   |   |   |   |'
a['two']='|   |   |   |   |   |'
#untill thirteen

vak = a.keys()
b = a #copy the dictionary
spot = a[vak[0]]
spot2 = b[vak[0]]
a[vak[0]] = spot[:(line_x)]+ d+ spot[(line_x+1):]
b[vak[0]] = spot2[:(line_x)]+ c+ spot2[(line_x+1):]

print a[vak[0]] #output_a = |   |   | A |   |   |
print b[vak[0]] #output_b = |   |   | A |   |   | <- which should be a 'B' in the middle
```

I'm having some trouble with making a copy of a dictionary and changing a value.
 
When I want to change a value in one of the dictionaries, the value of both the original and the copy change. But I only want the original to change and have the copy to change to something else. I can't seem to find the problem although it is in such a small and relatively easy code.

Comment: I have edited your question to add the code. In future please paste code in your question. It makes it easier for people to look at your code and give you an answer. If your code is too long (which it is not in your case) then you could consider condensing your code and pasting only the salient features relating to your problem in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`b = a` doesn't copy the dictionary, it rebinds `b` to point at the same object as `a` (so when you change `a`, you can observe the effect on `b` as well). Use `b = copy.copy(a)` ([`copy`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) module) instead.

Comment: For a shallow copy which you are creatin you could also simply use `b = dict(a)`

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I find `copy` to be more descriptive.

Comment: @ThiefMaster `copy.copy` is a shallow copy; `copy.deepcopy` exists for deep copying. The copy module is more general and it more explicit to use it for copying rather than taking the 'copy constructor' approach.

Answer (score 3):

The

```
b = a #copy the dictionary
```

does not copy the dictionary, just its reference. You have to copy it explicitly:

```
b = copy(a)
```

This will create a copy of the dictionary and you can manipulate with both and it will work. Just remember that mutable objects in dictionaries will change in both (if they are still present in both) if you change them in one. Take a look at this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_vs._Shallow_vs._Lazy_copy

Comment: Thank you both, this will certainly help!